# Cloud Shell Editor fails to load, 404 errors in Developer Tools console log in Chrome browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

This is problem only occurs in two developer PCs out of eight used by my team developing on GCP. Some of the team, when they launch the Google Cloud Shell Editor, see the editor load normally, while others see a spinner and the message

```
index.js:123 WebSocket connection to 'wss://970-dot-11840774-dot-devshell.appspot.com/services' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

in the Developer Tools console log when using Google Chrome.

We also see:

```
VM94663 bundle.js:67 Error: Connection timeout
    at VM94663 bundle.js:67
```

Problem is not resolved by:

- Restarting browser after clearing cache
- Running Google Cloud Shell Editor in Incognito Mode
- Running it in Firefox instead
- Starting the session in "Safe Mode", an option in the hamburger menu for Cloud Shell

I've tried the other fixes in similar posts here but they don't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions that might help:

1. Have you tried to using a different network? Might be an issue with Network Firewalls
2. Verify if there's no policy blocking gRPC protocol, that is used by the console, either on the network firewall or in the local machine settings